# titanium-mobile and cannot get value of veriable outside the function

Tags: javascript, titanium-mobile

I am not sure if I am being really stupid or just missed something, but basically I am trying to access the variable latitude and put it in the params variable so I can send it in a post request, however it doesn't seem to work, if I alert the variable latitude just before params outside the function I assign a value to it the alert returns blank. the  my code looks like the following:

```
var latitude;



    Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
                if (e.success) {
                    var user = eval('('+e.result+')');

                    var currentTime = new Date();
                    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
                    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
                    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
                    var day = currentTime.getDate();
                    var year = currentTime.getFullYear();                                               

                    if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) { 
                        Titanium.Geolocation.purpose = 'Get Current Location'; 
                        Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) { 
                            if (e.error) { 
                                alert('Error: ' + e.error); 
                            } else { 
                                latitude = e.coords.latitude;
                                longitude = e.coords.longitude;
                                accuracy = e.coords.accuracy;
                            } 
                        }); 
                    } else { 
                        alert('Please enable location services'); 
                    }

                    alert(latitude);

                    var params = {
                        username: user.username,
                        gender: user.gender,    
                        lastOnline:day+"/"+month+"/"+year+" -  "+hours+":"+minutes,
                        latitude:latitude,
                        //longitude:longitude,
                        //accuracy:e.coords.accuracy,
                    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is the standard "expecting an asynchronous function to behave synchronously" issue. While I'm not familiar with titanium-mobile, I'm guessing `Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an asynchronous function - that means that the callback function you specify won't have run by the time the next statement, `alert(latitude);`, executes.

To fix this, you need to make sure that anything requiring the geolocation to be set is invoked in the callback function, not before:

```
Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) { 
    if (e.error) { 
        alert('Error: ' + e.error); 
    } else { 

        var params = {
            username: user.username,
            gender: user.gender,    
            lastOnline: day+"/"+month+"/"+year+" -  "+hours+":"+minutes,
            latitude: e.coords.latitude,
            longitude: e.coords.longitude,
            accuracy: e.coords.accuracy
        };

        // now do something with params
        initializeStuff(params);
    } 
});
```

Comment: but then won't I get the same issue when trying to access params ? however I could do what ever I need within the function I am just thinking in the future I might need to access it from outside the function

Comment: You can access it from outside the callback, as long as you're sure the callback has returned. See my edit above - a common approach here, when you're fetching required info asynchronously, is to kick off an initialization function in the body of the callback.